# Using Session class of Laravel 4 in custom class

Tags: session, laravel

In my Laravel 4 app, I have custom class sCAPTCHA in app/custom_libs/scaptcha/sCAPTCHA.php

```
class sCAPTCHA
{
public Create()
{
//.....some code
Session::put('sCAPTCHA_code',$code);
```

then in the controller ScaptchaController

```
$scaptcha = new sCAPTCHA();
$scaptcha->Create();
```

and Laravel 4 throw me an error:

> Class 'scaptcha\Session' not found

It's very clear error, but how can I implement Session class of Laravel in my custom class sCAPTCHA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class sCAPTCHA
{
```

and now is working fine :)